# Como cargar un listbox con ADO.Net Entity Framework MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

estoy con un serio problema,no se como cargar un listbox con los datos de la base de datos...
Tengo una base de datos llamada el El Equipo del Siglo Seguros, y entre todas las tablas que tengo en la base, tengo la tabla llamada Provincia y cree un procedimiento almacenado llamado PA_ProvinciaSelect, la funcion de este procedimiento almacenado es traer el id de la provincia(identity) y el nombre de la provincia.

Cuando actualice el modelo de la base de datos, me apareció el PA_ProvinciaSelectResult, lo cree con el fin de que este procedimiento almacenado devolviera los registros,pero el problema es que no se como puedo hacer que los datos que se encuentran en la tabla Provincia aparezcan en el listbox para que el usuario pueda elegir la provincia en la que vive.

Este es el codigo que tengo en la vista

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="nombre">Provincia</label>
    <select name="Provincia" id="Provincia">
        <option>Seleccione una Provincia</option>
        @{
            foreach (ProyPVI.Models.PA_ProvinciaSelect_Result Provincia in ViewBag.Provincia) {

                <option value="@Provincia.Id_Provincia">@Provincia.Provincia</option>
            }
        }
    </select>
</div>
```

y este es codigo que tengo en el controlador

```
 public ActionResult Agregar() {



        return View();

    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Agregar(PA_UsuarioPolizaSelect_Result ModeloVista) {
        int RegistrosAfectados = ModeloBD.PA_ClienteInsert(ModeloVista.Cedula,
                                                           ModeloVista.Fecha_Nacimiento,
                                                           ModeloVista.Nombre,
                                                           ModeloVista.Apellido_1,
                                                           ModeloVista.Apellido_2,
                                                           ModeloVista.Id_Provincia,
                                                           ModeloVista.Id_Canton,
                                                           ModeloVista.Id_Distrito,
                                                           ModeloVista.Telefono_Principal,
                                                           ModeloVista.Telefono_Secundario,
                                                           ModeloVista.E_mail,
                                                           ModeloVista.id_genero,
                                                           ModeloVista.Id_Cobertura_Poliza,
                                                           ModeloVista.Direccion,
                                                           ModeloVista.Ultima_conexion);
        if (RegistrosAfectados >0) {

            ModelState.AddModelError("","Registro Insertado");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("","No se pudo insertar el cliente");
        }



        return View(ModeloVista);
    }
    public void AgregarLista()
    {
        List<PA_CantonSelect_Result> ModeloVista = new List<PA_CantonSelect_Result>();
        ModeloVista = ModeloBD.PA_CantonSelect("").ToList();

    }

}
```

Por favor,les agradecería mucho si me ayudan!!!! PD:El viewbag lo puse creyendo que me iba a traer todas los registros de la tabla provincia.....

Comment: Bienvenido @Aguero a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: No veo donde llenas el viewbag con las provincias

Comment: perdon,eso lo hice siguiendo un ejercicio de la universidad y se me olvido quitar el viewbag...... segun yo creía que el viewbag trae todos los datos de la tabla...el problema es que no se como hacer que los datos que tengo en la tabla provincia aparezcan en el listbox para que el usuario pueda elegirlas

Answer (score 0):

Al igual que en el insert debes invocar el procedure y obtener la respuesta

```
public ActionResult Agregar() {

    PA_ProvinciaSelectResult result = ModeloBD.PA_ProvinciaSelect(...);

    ViewBag.Provincias = result;

    return View();
}
```

Lo que si debes determinar es que tipo de dato retorna `PA_ProvinciaSelect` porque puede que el `PA_ProvinciaSelectResult` sea un objeto simple con una propiedad de lista o sea

```
List<PA_ProvinciaSelectResult> result = ModeloBD.PA_ProvinciaSelect(...);
```

una `List<>`

Dependiendo del tipo de datos es el que asignas a la propiedad del `ViewBag` que depsues iteras en la view